# Why am I getting a type error in my Dlookup function

Tags: ms-access-2013

Hi I have a `dlookup` in my expression builder in MS Access.

It involved dates, when I run it I get a type error.

Any ideas why that is?

```
=DLookUp("NewValue","[tblAuditTrail]","[frmName]='frmActionDetails' And ActionID='" & [Reports]![PATS_ACTIONID])
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the field `ActionID` is **string-valued**, you are missing a closing single quote surrounding the concatenated value:

```vb
=DLookUp
(
    "NewValue",
    "[tblAuditTrail]",
    "[frmName]='frmActionDetails' And ActionID='" & [Reports]![PATS_ACTIONID] & "'"
'                                                     You were missing this -----^
)
```

If, in fact, the `ActionID` contains a **numerical value** (as is likely the case for an ID), then no quotes are required, e.g.:

```vb
=DLookUp
(
    "NewValue",
    "[tblAuditTrail]",
    "[frmName]='frmActionDetails' And ActionID=" & [Reports]![PATS_ACTIONID]
'          Removed single quote from here -----^
)
```

Comment: It is a numerical value so that also was issue but I am still getting the error

Comment: @Tyrone In that case the error must originate elsewhere since the `DLookup` is syntactically correct.